# Join only visible rows from a column range in Excel 2016

Tags: excel-2016

My excel 2016 doesn't have the "textjoin" function, so I use a custom function that I called "joinlines", where the values of several lines of a column are joined in a single cell and separated by comma+space. The problem is that if there are hidden rows they are also returned in the join result.

Note:
The lines range is controlled by the `lCount and lSize` counters

See the function below:

```
Public Function JOINLINES(vArray As Variant, _
Optional lSize As Long, _
Optional sSeparator As String = ", ") As Variant
Dim v As Variant
Dim lCount As Long
Dim asOut() As String
 
If lSize < 0 Then
JOINLINES = CVErr(xlErrNum)
Exit Function
End If
 
For Each v In vArray                --.
If v <> "" Then                       | 
lCount = lCount + 1                   | here loads my array,
ReDim Preserve asOut(1 To lCount)     | but i want to load only 
asOut(lCount) = v                     | the visible cells
If lCount = lSize Then Exit For       | 
End If                                |
Next v                              --.
 
JOINLINES = Join(asOut, sSeparator)
End Function
```

How to put a command, in the function above, so that it "gets only the visible values" of the rows of the range selected in the column?

Comment: @Sumit Jain could you help me how can I select only the visible cells in my code in the question "Join only visible rows from a column range in Excel 2016"?